# Does event order matters in midi file

Tags: midi, midi-interface

I mean like the meta event comes first , then channel event, then sysevent , meta event etc.

[image]

In the picture there is one meta event that comes, then channel event, and in between what if we will shuffle the order?

Answer (score 0):

Most of these settings are independent, i.e., it does not matter in which order the events are processed.

However, some settings are affected by the current value of some other setting. For example, the program change events also uses the current values of the bank MSB/LSB controllers (this is not used in your file). Or the channel prefix (FF 20) meta event specifies the channel associated with the following meta or system exclusive events.

So if you don't know the meaning of an event, you should not reorder it.